# Jasmine custom matchers with a Protractor/WebDriverJS element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Hello fellow developers,

I would like to create my own custom matcher based on a Protractor/WebDriverJS element. Is anybody able to improve my current code ?

Here is what I would like to write in the specs files

```
var button = element(by.tagName('button'))
expect(button).toBeEnabled();
```

So here is my custom Jasmine matcher :

```
'use strict';

function matcher(util, customEqualityTesters) {
  return {
    compare : function (actual, expected) {
      var result = {};

      expect(actual.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy()

      result.pass = true;

      if (result.pass) {
        result.message = 'Expected element to be disabled';
      }
      else {
        result.message = 'Expected element to be enabled';
      }

      return result;
    }
  };
}

module.exports = matcher;
```

Is there a better way to write it ? Because at the moment, if I have an error, I have the following message: `Expected false to be true`. However I would like to get Expected element to be enabled.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but i feel that Jasmine custom matchers are objects which have the matchers as keys in them. So you have to call it using the object key. However, you are hard coding the `result.pass = true;` value, which causes your `else` to never be executed in case of a failure and your statement `'Expected element to be enabled.'` will never be printed. Here's how you can improve it -

```
'use strict';

var customMatchers = {
    toBeEnabled: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return {
            compare : function (actual, expected) {
            var result = {};

            result.pass = actual.isEnabled();

            if (result.pass) {
                result.message = 'Expected element to be enabled';
            }
            else {
                result.message = 'Expected element to be disabled';
            }

              return result;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use it -

```
var button = element(by.tagName('button'))
expect(button).toBeEnabled();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @prbaron if it solved your issue, then mark it as answer so that it helps others. Thanks